# Text to Speech doesn't stop when fragment changes in navigation drawer

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my project, I'm using Navigation drawer with fragments. In 1st screen(1st fragment), I have a dashboard. On 2nd fragment, I'm having tts with large amount of text in button click. It works fine and stops fine, only when fragment is back to 1st fragment(dashboard).

**Issue:** When fragment changes by selecting in navigation menu, tts doesn't stop.Even I go to next fragment, tts is playing.

I used onDestroy(),onPause(), onResume(), onStop(). Nothing works.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() { //same for other methods also
    super.onDestroy();
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I use **add** in fragment stack

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment,back_stack_name);
transaction.addToBackStack(back_stack_name);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Is the text you're playing very long?

Comment: Its length is 4234. But it works fine upto the last word by splitting the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, once a piece of text is started, it seems to be impossible to stop it.

One possibility would be to use the `synthesizeToFile` capability to create an audio file of the the TTS output, you'll have more control over the playback then.

The other possibility (which I have implemented) is to split the text in smaller parts (I just used the full-stop `.`) and play these one after another, using the `UtteranceProgressListener`'s `onDone` method (when one part is done, play the next one). It sounds just the same, and when you can manually stop the playback by just not playing the `n+1` part after part `n` has played.
Ugly workaround, I know.

Comment: OK, let me try this. Im not familiar with synthesizeToFile and utterance. Can u give me an example?

Comment: Don't have the project here, sorry.